# React Native - Handling <Text/> to used "SecureTextEntry" like <TextInput/>

Tags: react-native, text

I'm tried to find any props in react native docs how to used `<Text/>` to hide `Password` Text,

I have a dynamic JS Object to show and used `map` to handle:

```
renderProfile(){
  var tampil = this.state.data[0].detail.map((item, index)=>{
    return(
      <View key={index}>
        <Text>{item.Header} :</Text>
        {
          this.state.editProfile ?
          item.Header == 'Password' || item.Header == 'Username' || item.Header == 'Telepon' ?
          <View>
          <TextInput
            //MyProps
          />
          {item.Header=='Password' && this.state.editProfile ? <FontAwesome onPress={()=>{this.setState({hidePassword: !this.state.hidePassword})}} name="eye" size={20} color="#000"/> : null}
          </View>
          : <Text>{item.Value}</Text>
          : <Text>{item.Value}</Text>
        }
      </View>
    )
  })
  return tampil
}
```

I can handle the `<TextInput/>` with `SecureTextEntry`, but on `<Text/>` I don't see `SecureTextEntry props`

Is there a way to hide Password in `<Text/>` component?

Comment: Why don't you just use a <TextInput /> and set `editable={false}`?

Comment: I've tried it, but when the `editable=true` and I'm edited the text, I got an error,

Comment: which error are you facing?

Comment: [i got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msvMv.png)

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no prop to hide the password in the [`Text`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#props) and you want to use the `Text` node, then you can make your own *text mask*.

```
securePasswordEntry (value) { 
  return value && value.replace(/./g, '*')
}

<Text>{securePasswordEntry(/*Text you want to secure*/)}<Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use TextInput for Password fields.

```
<View>
    <TextInput secureTextEntry={true}>
    </TextInput>
</View>
```

Comment: I'm already know if `<TextInput/>` has `secureTextEntry`, I want to implement it on `<Text/>`

Comment: If you want to use it with **<Text>**  you should use **onChangeText** property and then replace the passwordText with dot like **passwordText.replace(".*", ".")**